# Magento installation takes so much time

Tags: magento-1.8, installation

I am trying to install magento-1.8 on local server. Its takes so much time to installation process. I am trying install half an hour but still is process is not complete.

Process running during Database Configuration.

I have configure database like

Host: localhost:9292 (9292 is my port)

Database Name : magento

User : root

I am facing this situation first time. I don't know, why is happing.

Comment: you should mention just `localhost` without port number.

Comment: how many disk space and ram is left on your system.
does php or mysql have a high cpu usage?
On unix systems you have the command line tool "iotop", how is the write rate for mysql?

Comment: sounds like you shouldn't be installing Magento until you can manage a local LAMP stack properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused between two hostnames:

- **Database** configuration hostname is `localhost`  whereas
- **Webserver** hostname is `localhost:9292`

So, mention just `localhost` in hostname.

If this doesn't work then check what is the hostname by opening the respective database software.

In phpMyAdmin, it is by default `localhost` which you can check as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: if I have mention localhost then problem come like this "        The URL "http://localhost:9292/magento/" is invalid.
        Response from server isn't valid."

Comment: Thank you @Mr_Green. I have solve the issue with your help. In Magento 1.8 there option is available like " Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step".

Comment: @PrashantParekh good and thanks for letting me know this :)

Answer (score -1):

I think if you import sample data from magentocommerce to your database (that you created before), then install your magento, this can solve your problem and pass steps very fast